# Line not being drawn in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouse, paint

I'm making GUI Builder. There's menu bar at the top, and left side is attribute pane, the right side is editor pane.

I make a class `UserPanel` which extends `JPanel`

In my class `UserPanel`, there's a `paint()` method which is supposed to get a point where the mouse is pressed, get the point where the mouse is released, and draw a line between them, but the `paint()` method was never called. I set a BreakPoint and debugged, but `paint()` was still never called. I added `revalidate()` method at the end of each `mouseListener` method also.

I want to draw rectangle at `EditorPane`.

Why did my `paint()` method not execute, and how can I fix it?

```
Container BigContainer ;
JPanel AttributePane ;
JPanel EditorPane ;
Point pStart = null ;
Point pFlexible = null ;

class GUI_Buider extends JFrame
{
    BigContainer = new Container () ;
    BorderLayout Border1 = new BorderLayout ( 20 , 10 ) ;
    BigContainer.setLayout ( Border1 ) ;

    AttributePane = new JPanel () ;
    BigContainer.add ( AttributePane , Border1.WEST ) ;

    EditorPane = new JPanel () ;
    BigContainer.add ( EditorPane , Border1.WEST ) ;

    UserMouse usermouse = new UserMouse () ;
    getContentPane ().addMouseListener ( usermouse ) ;

    UserPanel pan = new UserPanel () ;
    getCotentPane ().add ( pan ) ;

}
```

.

```
class UserPanel extends JPanel
{
    UserPanel ()
    {
        super.revalidate () ;
        revalidate () ;
    }
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        if ( ( null != pStart ) && ( null != pFlexible ) )
            g.drawLine ( pStart.x , pStart.y , pFlexible.x , pFlexible.y ) ;

        revalidate () ;
    }

    public void paint ( Graphics g )
    {
        if ( ( null != pStart ) && ( null != pFlexible ) )
            g.drawLine ( pStart.x , pStart.y , pFlexible.x , pFlexible.y ) ;

        revalidate () ;
    }
}
class UserMouse implements MouseListenr
{
    // I implement mouseEntered, mouseExited, mouseClicked

    public void mousePressed ( MouseEvent e )
    {
        pStart = e.getPoint () ;
    }
    public void mouseReleased ( MouseEvent e )
    {
        pFlexible = e.getPoint () ;
        revalidate () ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code where you attached your mouselistener to your panel?

Comment: Instead of just guessing what will work and overriding every paint method “shotgun style,” read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ and learn how to properly implement custom painting.  (You *definitely* should not call revalidate() from a paint method.)

Comment: `There's menu bar at the top, and left side is attribute pane, the right side is editor pane.` - so where is the "UserPanel"? Does the "UserPane" have a size. If the size is (0, 0) there is nothing to paint. Read the tutorial link given by VGR, it shows how to override the getPreferredSize() method.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @camickr I add code that I attached at the top of the code. I' sorry to give short information. UserPanel is just paint tool. But it really needed to had a size?

Comment: @csm_dev I add code that I attached at the top of the code. I'm really sorry to give short information.

Comment: You still have not shown where you attach the mouselistener to any of your components.

Comment: `But it really needed to had a size?` - do you know how layout managers work? Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). We have no idea how you add the components to the frame. You haven't posted an `MCVE / SSCCE` as suggested by Andrew hours ago, so we can't help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I add some code with JPanel, Container, and MouseListener. I'm sorry to disappoint.

Comment: @csm_dev I'm sorry. I add some code where mouselistener attached, and some informations. I'm sorry to disappoint.

Comment: @camickr I really appreciate to you. I just think "UserPanel" have to be add to some Panel that I want to draw. But it's not. I have to replace "EditorPane" to "UserPanel". I'm really sorry to give you disappointment. And I have some composure, and I understand what you say. I really really appreciate to you. I want you to answer this question, and some developers like me can solve problem. Thanks. Have a good day :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I fix the problem. Thanks to concern. Have a good day :)

Comment: @csm_dev I fix the problem. Thanks to worry me. Have a good day :)